# Sourcetree - Bitbucket - Recover deleted commit push (Made for other person)

Tags: git, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree, macos-mojave

I'm facing the next bad situation:

I'm working in Mac with Sourcetree and Bitbucket, and accidentally **I deleted a committed push made for other person**.

When I open Sourcetree I saw a commit made by a colleague and I tried to pull the changes made by him, but Sourcetree didn't let me (I forgot the reason), so I do my commit and push (I do a git push --force) and now I don't see the commit made by that person.

In Sourcetree in History, the commit push that he made are not in list.

The worst part: That guy is no longer in the company.

I tried to reverse the commit that I made, but I don't have positive results.

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: If you can't access the guy's local repo and you never pulled his commits, you're out of luck.  Force pushing to the origin repo is almost always a bad idea for this reason.

Comment: I have access to the repository. I'm admin. Could I do anything?

Comment: Is his/her commit on another branch?  Was there a PR?  Otherwise, probably not.  Generally, in this situation, you could use `git reflog` to locate the lost commit, but you need command line access to the repo that had the commit.

Comment: The branch is master and no PR.

Comment: sorry to say, I think that commit has joined the eternal void, unless you can get access to your colleague's machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi team: Thanks for your comments. I already could speak with that guy and he did the commit again.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try find this commit using `git reflog`?
[Example](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection#_git_reflog)

Or try to fix things up with
[rebase](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing).